# Conditional checking in google sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a google sheet where students input their name, id, and time in a google form, and so far the only way the faculty have checked if students skipped or not is by tediously checking every name is there, and on that specific day.

I need a bit of help creating a program so a user could input a day and it would go through a list of all the names that are in the specific day and output any that are missing.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a programmer, you just need the data to be displayed in a different way on a new sheet.

1. Create a new sheet
2. List all the student names and IDs in columns A and B
3. Put the dates that you want to check in a row above the names and IDs in columns C,D,E... etc.
4. Next to the first ID use `countifs` to count the number of times on your responses sheet the ID and date match the ID on that row and the date above.
5. If you create your countifs formula correctly and lock the ranges properly then you can autofill down an across and get something similar to my example below.

```
            2 Mar 17  3 Mar 17
Bill Gates     0         1
Steve Jobs     1         1
```

I can't create an exact formula for you without knowing how your data is setup but here's an example.

```
=countifs('Response Sheet'!C:C,$B2,'Response Sheet'!D:D,C$1)
```

The formula would go into cell C3 on the sheet you create with names in column A, IDs in column B and dates from C1 along the top. It assumes that your IDs are listed in column C on your form responses sheet and dates in column D.

Notice how the B2 reference is locked $B2 so that as you autofill across it keeps comparing the ID in column B and the date cell C1 is locked C$1 to always compare with the first row even when you autofill down.

Once your table is complete you can add a sum formula at the bottom to show the total students for each day.

Comment: ok, but how can i get a list of exactly whos not on this list.

Comment: The students with zero next to their name are not on the list for that particular date. In my example Bill Gates on the second of March.